# How to replace first n no. of occurrence of a string using sed and/or awk?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I got a file `alphabet` where `a` has multiple occurrence in a line.

```
$ cat alphabet
a b c d e f g 
h i j k a a l
m n a p q r a
s t u v w a x
y z a k l q z
```

where

```
$ cat alphabet | grep -o a | wc -l
7
```

Now how can I replace only first 3 occurrence of `a` with `Z` so that my file looks like as follows

```
Z b c d e f g 
h i j k Z Z l
m n a p q r a
s t u v w a x
y z a k l q z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        if ($i == "a" && n < 3) {
            n++
            $i = "Z"
        }
    print
}' alphabet
```

Or, "one-liner"-ed

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="a" && n++<3) $i="Z"; print}' alphabet
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: It's not very complicated code. Do you have any particular questions?

Comment: No, but future readers of the answer might ...

Comment: Note that this will find only occurrences of `a` that are separate words.  While this is true of the *example* data, it is not specified as being true of the real data.  Also, if this changes a line that contains strings of multiple spaces (e.g., `c   a   t        d o g`), it will cause those spaces to collapse to single ones (`c Z t d o g`).

Answer (score 4):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe '$c++ while $c < 3 && s/a/Z/' alphabet
```

Comment: -1 He said using sed and/or awk, and you didn't even mention them

Comment: Compact and beautiful. You also have Perl in most cases you've got Bash

Answer (score 2):

Here, the sed way

`sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s#a#Z#;s#a#Z#;s#a#Z#' alphabet`

Since sed normaly works on lines, any command to sed will act only on 1 line at a time. To be able to replace only the first 3 occurances we need to first make the whole file a single selection on which we will do our 3 replacements. Otherwise we will do 3 replacements on each line.

- `:a` creates a label
- `N` appends next line into patterns space
- `$!` skips last newline
- `ba` branches to label `a`

We have now selected the whole file and will be acting on that space instead on one line at a time, do 3 replacements of "a" with "Z".

The above command will only work on GNU sed, more general but a bit uglier version that should work on non-GNU sed:

`sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's#a#Z#' -e 's#a#Z#' -e 's#a#Z#'  alphabet`

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, adding version which uses g command to first replace all occurrences of 'a' with 'Z' and then replace all occurrences of 'Z' after 3th with 'a' again, which effectively leads to replacing only the first 3 occurrences of 'a'. This way you can change the last number to reflect the number of substitutions you need.

`sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s#a#Z#g;s#Z#a#g4' alphabet`

Comment: In order to have a more general solution, I'd set number of chars (+1) to be replaced: `':a;N;$!ba;s#\n#<NL>#g;s#a#Z#g;s#Z#a#4g;s#<NL>#\n#g'` i.e. replace **all** occurrences with "Z", then put back "a" in place starting from the 4th occurrence of "Z".

Comment: Actually I think s#\n#<NL>#g / s#<NL>#\n#g is not needed...

Comment: @SalvoF I have considered this but in my tests it was not working in some versions of GNU sed when using gN > 4, probably a bug not sure...

Comment: Which versions? I tried three different ones, one of which running on Vista (where I had to use double quotes instead of single, and to double newlines' backslash)

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` solution that has been posted
assumes that all the occurrences of `a` are separate words. 
While this is true of the *example* data,
it is not specified as being true of the real data. 
The following `awk` solution
is more in the spirit of the `perl` solution that has been posted:

```
awk '{ while (changes < 3  &&  sub("a", "Z") > 0) changes++; print }' alphabet
```

This replaces (**sub**stitutes) occurrences of `a` with `Z`
until the `changes` counter reaches 3. 
Of course, to actually change the file, you will need to do something like

```
awk '{while (c < 3 && sub("a","Z")>0) c++; print}' alphabet > t && cp t alphabet && rm t
```

where `t` is a temporary file.

Comment: On GNU awk, starting from version 4.10, you have [in-place file editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)